# How does Scott Lang afford to live in a townhouse in San Francisco?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, ant-man-and-the-wasp

I noticed in Ant-Man and the Wasp that Scott Lang (AKA Ant-Man) lives by himself in what looks like a 3-storey heritage townhouse in San Francisco, which is [a very expensive city to live in](https://smartasset.com/mortgage/what-is-the-cost-of-living-in-san-francisco).

When Scott Lang was released from prison in Ant-Man, he had to move in with his friend Luis and was unable to make his child support payments, so he couldn't have money saved up from the period before Ant-Man. In Ant-Man and the Wasp, we know that Scott Lang's business (X-Con Security) isn't doing well, because Luis says so. Could he have another source of income? Could he have made a great deal of money between the two Ant-Man films?

**TL;DR:** Given his financial situation and the city's highly competitive real estate market, how does Scott Lang afford to live in such an expensive home?

Comment: He partnered up with a rich super scientist in Ant-Man. Perhaps they're paying for - or already owned - the house? Purely speculation, though, and no evidence on which to make this an actual answer.

Comment: I attribute it to movie magic. Seems similar to movies with heroes that don't have jobs, and kids who never need to go to school. (And Kiefer Sutherland never needing to pee in _24_.)

Comment: @AnthonyGrist there is a scene in the beginning, when Scott went to the lab for the first time, where he has even offered money to help Hope in case they needed. She said they were doing fine and the door opened to show a super-high-expensive-tech lab. He offered money because Hope was complaining they were switching places very often to escape from the police.

Comment: @Zanon I haven't seen the new movie (it doesn't release here until August), which is why I commented and said I had no evidence.

Comment: After watching Ant-Man again, I think I have an answer. Assuming Scott Lang owned part or all of the X-Con Security business, he may have made a great deal of money from its earlier success (another assumption). This money would have allowed him to purchase a townhouse in San Francisco with the help of a mortgage.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

He lives in Apartment 2A, on the third floor of the building (which also includes the upstairs attic, making it two floors). You can see this when he's standing at his front door, which opens directly into a stairway, and the apartment number is on the door when the FBI burst in.

He also shares the place with Luis, who's wearing PJs, and is surprised to see the giant ant taking Scott's place. Luis is also there later, talking to Scott on the phone, and also says he hates the way Scott loads the dishwasher, so they're splitting the rent.

Furthermore, it's almost a year between the events of *Ant-Man* and *Civil War*, and then two years on house arrest after that, so there were almost three years in which to start and grow the X-Con security firm.

And while the business was on the brink of bankruptcy, it had a very well equipped office space, and had at least four employees, so we can infer that there was at least enough cash flow to cover their rent (for the time being).

He also repaired his relationship with his ex-wife (and her new husband), so she may have been helping out financially.

Comment: Congratulations, this is the winner of the [monthly answer challenge](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4417/49).